# Select from nested select T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wish to modify data by selecting them in a inner query 
and count one of them modified.. 
It gives error..

```
select count(cvs) from
(
  select 
  cvs,
  (case Citycode when 123 then 'test' else 'other' end) as CityName ,
  (case ProductCode when '000' then 'test3' when 'ss' then 'xtr' else 'ddd' end) as CardName
  from Applications
)
```

Comment: If all you care about is the count, why are you selecting all of that other data?  You're not grouping or aggregating any of the sub query data, so why not just select the count without the sub query?

Comment: Probably all you are missing is an alias. `Select Count(*) from (...) A`

Comment: my case is quite different just I simplify the question guys.. But it solved by using giving the alias of the query.. thx for help

Answer (score 79, accepted):

you need to give an alias to the subquery:

```
select count(x.cvs) from
(
  select 
  cvs,
  (case Citycode when 123 then 'test' else 'other' end) as CityName ,
  (case ProductCode when '000' then 'test3' when 'ss' then 'xtr' else 'ddd' end) as CardName
  from Applications
) x
```

Comment: This was what I am looking for =)) thanx Dalen !!! I know how to count but my case was different.. I guess he get what I am looking for...

Comment: Glad it helped, next time explain a little better what you are looking for so you'll avoid all that downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this instead?

```
SELECT COUNT(cvs)
    FROM Applications
```

Comment: I'm guessing *(hoping)* he has more logic he didn't include

Answer (score 0):

It appears your query could be simplified to..

```
SELECT COUNT(cvs) FROM Applications
```

Is there a reason you have the select nested and you are ignoring the other columns being selected?

Comment: thx Quintin but my case was related by using alias for sub query

Answer (score 0):

**Two things I see off the bat:**

1 - You don't need the nested subquery for what you are doing in the example.  You could just as easily do:

`SELECT COUNT(cvs) FROM application`

2 - You need an alias for the subquery, like `(<subquery>) as SubQ`